# Desk door with strange holder in door

Tags: furniture

I just bought a desk from a second hand store. The inside of one door has these strange holders inside. The bottom one is missing the black cover.

Any idea what this holder is for?
[image]

Comment: Looks to me like a tool holder. The lower section may not have had a front, and have been intended just to help keep the tools from swinging when the door was opened or closed. Re what kinds of tools: it's a pretty general design for anything from screwdrivers to chisels to anything of the same basic long-thing-witg-handle shape, so I'm not going to try to guess.

Comment: Yep, if the door was taller, I'd guess it was for holding brooms and the like.